# haskell - pointfree catch one argument two times

Tags: haskell, generator

this code works in Haskell:

```
x a = (a + 1, a + 2)
x 2 -- returns (3, 4)
```

while this not:

```
x = ((+1), (+2))

<interactive>:935:1: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `Integer -> t'
              with actual type `(Integer -> Integer, Integer -> Integer)'
* The function `x' is applied to one argument,
  but its type `(Integer -> Integer, Integer -> Integer)' has none
  In the expression: x 2
  In an equation for `it': it = x 2
* Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:935:1)
```

Can someone explain me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This part of the error explains the gist of it:

> The function `x` is applied to one argument,
>   but its type `(Integer -> Integer, Integer -> Integer)` has none

When you write a function point-free, you write it in such a way that, given more arguments after the expression, it will evaluate to the desired result. For example:

```hs
x a = 1 + a
-- same as:
x' = (1+)
-- because when you use it:
x 3 == 1 + 3 == 4
x' 3 == (1+) 3 == 4
```

This is not the case with how you wrote your tuple function, because Haskell doesn't know that you want a tuple of functions to be used as a function.

```hs
x a = (1 + a, 2 + a)
-- not the same as:
x' = ((1+), (2+))
-- because:
x 1 == (1 + 1, 2 + 1) == (2, 3)
x' 1 == ((1+), (2+)) 1 == ???
```

You can check [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/), which translates your function to:

```hs
x = liftM2 (,) (1 +) (2 +)
```

Which uses the fact that tuples are monads (and is better described in the other answer), but is arguably less readable.

Comment: thanks, I this using liftM2 is less readable than simple (a + 1, a + 2)

Comment: @bratpiorka `liftM2` (or the more general applicative-functor versions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58836537/1126841) are useful when you need to combine arbitrary functions (that you, say, receive as arguments), rather than expressions that you can construct yourself. After a while, you get used to the idiom and it becomes more readable.

Answer (score 5):

What you here constructed is a 2-tuple where each element is a function. That is all. A 2-tuple is not a function, so you can not just use it and apply an argument to it.

You can here make use of the fact that a function is an [**`Applicative`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Applicative) instance, and thus work with:

```
x :: Num a => a -> (a, a)
x = (,) <$> (1+) <*> (2+)
```

or by using `liftA2` which does the same thing:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

x :: Num a => a -> (a, a)
x = liftA2 (,) (1+) (2+)
```